# xkb: Assign a new shift level to function keys

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm trying to get some more use out of my function keys.  I would like the physical <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd> keys to appear as `F21` to `F32`, so I can assign functions to `F21` etc. in my window manager (e.g. switch to the active chat window whenever I press `F22`.)

However I still want access to the normal function keys, so I would like to be able to hold the physical <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key and press <kbd>F1</kbd> to generate an `F1` keypress.  As far as the other modifiers go, it would be nice if they were left unchanged, so <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> produces `Shift + F1` (not `Shift + F21`).  In summary:

- <kbd>F1</kbd> -> `F21`
- <kbd>Caps</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> -> `F1`
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> -> `Shift + F1` (unchanged)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> -> `Alt + F1` (unchanged)
- etc.

So only the first two dot points require changes from the default layout.

I have attempted to start this with the following XKB snippet, and while it produces `F21` for <kbd>F1</kbd>, it does not produce the original F-keys when <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is held:

```
partial
xkb_types "hyper" {
    virtual_modifiers Alt,Hyper;
    type "HYPER" {
        modifiers= Hyper+Control+Alt;
        map[Hyper]= Level2;
        map[Control+Alt]= Level3;
        level_name[Level1]= "Extra";
        level_name[Level2]= "Normal";
        level_name[Level3]= "Normal+Ctrl+Alt";
    };
};

partial function_keys
xkb_symbols "hyper_f21" {

    replace key <FK01> {
        type= "HYPER",
        symbols[Group1]= [           F21,             F1, XF86Switch_VT_1 ]
    };
    replace key <FK02> {
        type= "HYPER",
        symbols[Group1]= [           F22,             F2, XF86Switch_VT_2 ]
    };
    ...
};

partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "caps_hyper" {
    replace key <CAPS> {
        [ Hyper_L, Hyper_L ]
    };
    modifier_map Lock { <KPDL> };  # Not sure how to clear modifiers, so assign an unused key
    modifier_map Mod3 { <CAPS> };
};
```

When I try to load it, I get this warning:

```
Warning:          Type "HYPER" has 3 levels, but <FK01> has 5 symbols
                  Ignoring extra symbols
```

I don't really understand why I get the error, because although the default `<FK01>` has five levels, my redefined one only has three.

When I test out this configuration, sure enough I get `F21` when pressing the physical <kbd>F1</kbd> key, and I get `Hyper_L` (and `Mod3`) set when pressing <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.  However pressing <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> produces `Mod3 + F21` instead of `F1`.

Answer (score 7):

As always, figured this one out moments after posting the question.  The problem was simply that I was using `Hyper_L` which by default is assigned to `Mod4`.  By changing <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to `Hyper_R` instead, it worked.  It still had to be bound to `Mod3` though as a real modifier is still needed.

Here's the updated config which now produces the desired behaviour:

```
partial
xkb_types "hyper" {
    virtual_modifiers Alt,Hyper;

    type "HYPER" {
        modifiers= Shift+Control+Alt+Hyper;

        map[Shift]= Level2;
        preserve[Shift]= Shift;

        map[Control]= Level2;
        preserve[Control]= Control;

        map[Shift+Control]= Level2;
        preserve[Shift+Control]= Shift+Control;

        map[Alt]= Level2;
        preserve[Alt]= Alt;

        map[Shift+Alt]= Level2;
        preserve[Shift+Alt]= Shift+Alt;

        map[Control+Alt]= Level3;
        preserve[Control+Alt]= Control+Alt;

        map[Shift+Control+Alt]= Level2;
        preserve[Shift+Control+Alt]= Shift+Alt;

        map[Hyper]= Level2;

        level_name[Level1]= "Extra";
        level_name[Level2]= "Normal";
        level_name[Level3]= "Ctrl+Alt";
    };
};


partial function_keys
xkb_symbols "hyper_f21" {

    replace key <FK01> {
        type= "HYPER",
        symbols[Group1]= [           F21,             F1, XF86Switch_VT_1 ]
    };
    replace key <FK02> {
        type= "HYPER",
        symbols[Group1]= [           F22,             F2, XF86Switch_VT_2 ]
    };
    ...
};

partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "caps_hyper" {
    replace key <CAPS> {
        [ Hyper_R ]
    };
    # Remove Hyper (Hyper_L/Hyper_R) from Mod4, was added by "pc" layout
    modifier_map none { <HYPR> };
    # Now make physical caps lock (mapped to Hyper_R above) control Mod3.  Mod3 is
    # associated with the virtual modifier "Hyper" because the existing XKB config
    # links Hyper_L and Hyper_R with this virtual modifier.  Therefore Mod3 becomes
    # the virtual modifier "Hyper" because they both share the same keysym Hyper_R.
    modifier_map Mod3 { <CAPS> };
};
```

Again, this does:

- <kbd>F1</kbd> -> `F21`
- <kbd>Caps</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> -> `F1`
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> -> `Shift + F1` (unchanged)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> -> `Alt + F1` (unchanged)
- etc. - all others unchanged

Comment: `preserve` is treated like `map` by xkbcomp, so it throws a warning on warning level 10. (`preserve` should actually be doing something according to documentation...)